# Android Eclipse - Clicking on multiple buttons quickly crashes my app

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm new to developing apps for Android, and I'm using Eclipse for this purpose.

I have a class/activity with several buttons in it. These buttons each launch a different activity once clicked. Most of the time, this works fine - I can click one button to launch activity1, click the back button to terminate activity1, and click on another button to launch activity2.

However, I've found out that if I exit activity1, and then quickly (within 1 second of leaving activity1) click on the button to launch activity2, my app crashes. I've tried searching for solutions online, but haven't come across anything.

Is there a way I can avoid situations where clicking the buttons this quickly crashes the app?

Thanks! Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is the code for my class:

```
public class CharPicker extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageButton otherHeader;
ImageButton char1, char2, char3, char4, char5, char6, char7, char8, char9, char10;

private boolean clicked; // Determines if a character was selected.

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // Sets the view to the character picker screen.
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_charpicker);

    // Set audio manager to handle volume changes in music/audio. 
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    otherHeader = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.otherHeader); // Other header.

    char1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.first); // Char1 icon. 
    char2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.second); // Char2 icon.
    char3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.third); // Char3 icon.
    char4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fourth); // Char4 icon.
    char5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fifth); // Char5 icon.
    char6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sixth); // Char6 icon.
    char7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.seventh); // Char7 icon.
    char8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.eighth); // Char8 icon.
    char9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ninth); // Char9 icon.
    char10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.tenth); // Char10 icon.

    otherHeader.setOnClickListener(this);

    char1.setOnClickListener(this);
    char2.setOnClickListener(this);
    char3.setOnClickListener(this);
    char4.setOnClickListener(this);
    char5.setOnClickListener(this);
    char6.setOnClickListener(this);
    char7.setOnClickListener(this);
    char8.setOnClickListener(this);
    char9.setOnClickListener(this);
    char10.setOnClickListener(this);

    clicked = false;
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    // Resets clicked boolean to false so another character can be selected.
    super.onStart();
    if(clicked == true)
        clicked = false;
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    // Resets clicked boolean to false so another character can be selected.
    super.onResume();
    if(clicked == true)
        clicked = false;
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    // Sets clicked boolean to true to avoid crashing cases arising from multiple concurrent button clicks.
    super.onPause();
    if(clicked == false)
        clicked = true;
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
    // Sets clicked boolean to true to avoid crashing cases arising from multiple concurrent button clicks.
    super.onStop();
    if(clicked == false)
        clicked = true;
}

public void onClick(View view){
    // Determines which instruction screen to load up as an activity.
    // Creates a new activity.

    switch(view.getId()){
        case(R.id.otherHeader):
            if(clicked == false){
                // Clicking on this returns user to the home page.
                // Terminates this activity.
                clicked = true;
                finish();
            }
        case(R.id.first):
            if(clicked == false){
                Intent collection1Char1 = new Intent(this, Collection1Char1.class);
                startActivity(collection1Char1);
                clicked = true;
            }
            break;
        case(R.id.second):
            if(clicked == false){
                Intent collection1Char2 = new Intent(this, Collection1Char2.class);
                startActivity(collection1Char2);
                clicked = true;
            }
            break;
        case(R.id.third):
            if(clicked == false){
                Intent collection1Char3 = new Intent(this, Collection1Char3.class);
                startActivity(collection1Char3);
                clicked = true;
            }
            break;
        case(R.id.fourth):
            if(clicked == false){
                Intent collection1Char4 = new Intent(this, Collection1Char4.class);
                startActivity(collection1Char4);
                clicked = true;
            }
            break;
        case(R.id.fifth):
            if(clicked == false){
                Intent collection1Char5 = new Intent(this, Collection1Char5.class);
                startActivity(collection1Char5);    
                clicked = true;
            }
            break;
        case(R.id.sixth):
            if(clicked == false){
                Intent collection1Char6 = new Intent(this, Collection1Char6.class);
                startActivity(collection1Char6);
                clicked = true;
            }
            break;
        case(R.id.seventh):
            if(clicked == false){
                Intent collection1Char7 = new Intent(this, Collection1Char7.class);
                startActivity(collection1Char7);
                clicked = true;
            }
            break;
        case(R.id.eighth):
            if(clicked == false){
                Intent collection1Char8 = new Intent(this, Collection1Char8.class);
                startActivity(collection1Char8);    
                clicked = true;
            }
            break;
        case(R.id.ninth):
            if(clicked == false){
                Intent collection1Char9 = new Intent(this, Collection1Char9.class);
                startActivity(collection1Char9);    
                clicked = true;
            }
            break;
        case(R.id.tenth):
            if(clicked == false){
                Intent collection1Char10 = new Intent(this, Collection1Char10.class);
                startActivity(collection1Char10);   
                clicked = true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Below is the logcat:

```
12-15 17:36:47.698: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 154K, 9% free 14686K/15971K, paused 17ms
12-15 17:36:47.708: I/dalvikvm-heap(28552): Grow heap (frag case) to 17.289MB for 2406416-byte allocation
12-15 17:36:47.728: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 17036K/18339K, paused 16ms
12-15 17:36:47.778: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_CONCURRENT freed 589K, 11% free 16465K/18339K, paused 2ms+2ms
12-15 17:36:47.798: D/memalloc(28552): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d709000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:51
12-15 17:36:47.818: D/CLIPBOARD(28552): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
12-15 17:36:49.029: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 198K, 6% free 17870K/18979K, paused 13ms
12-15 17:36:49.039: I/dalvikvm-heap(28552): Grow heap (frag case) to 20.495MB for 2508016-byte allocation
12-15 17:36:49.059: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 6% free 20318K/21475K, paused 2ms+2ms
12-15 17:36:49.089: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 612K, 9% free 20319K/22115K, paused 12ms
12-15 17:36:49.099: I/dalvikvm-heap(28552): Grow heap (frag case) to 22.886MB for 2508016-byte allocation
12-15 17:36:49.119: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 8% free 22768K/24611K, paused 2ms+1ms
12-15 17:36:49.149: D/memalloc(28552): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5dba1000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:58
12-15 17:36:52.433: D/memalloc(28552): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d609000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:51
12-15 17:36:52.583: D/memalloc(28552): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5df39000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:54
12-15 17:36:52.663: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3533K, 17% free 22033K/26339K, paused 13ms
12-15 17:36:52.703: D/memalloc(28552): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5e2d1000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:64
12-15 17:36:54.174: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_CONCURRENT freed 557K, 9% free 24190K/26339K, paused 1ms+3ms
12-15 17:36:54.225: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 577K, 8% free 26392K/28387K, paused 15ms
12-15 17:36:54.265: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 502K, 7% free 28892K/30947K, paused 15ms
12-15 17:36:54.295: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 500K, 7% free 30892K/32995K, paused 15ms
12-15 17:36:54.345: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1001K, 8% free 34394K/37091K, paused 21ms
12-15 17:36:54.425: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1001K, 7% free 38895K/41699K, paused 28ms
12-15 17:36:54.485: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1001K, 7% free 42896K/45795K, paused 18ms
12-15 17:36:54.535: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1001K, 7% free 46898K/49891K, paused 15ms
12-15 17:36:54.545: V/MediaPlayer(28552): constructor
12-15 17:36:54.545: V/MediaPlayer(28552): setListener
12-15 17:36:54.545: V/MediaPlayer(28552): setDataSource(49, 20974933, 217100)
12-15 17:36:54.565: V/MediaPlayer(28552): setVideoSurfaceTexture
12-15 17:36:54.565: V/MediaPlayer(28552): prepare
12-15 17:36:54.565: V/MediaPlayer(28552): message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
12-15 17:36:54.565: V/MediaPlayer(28552): New video size 0 x 0
12-15 17:36:54.565: V/MediaPlayer(28552): callback application
12-15 17:36:54.565: V/MediaPlayer(28552): back from callback
12-15 17:36:54.565: V/MediaPlayer(28552): message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
12-15 17:36:54.565: V/MediaPlayer(28552): prepared
12-15 17:36:54.565: V/MediaPlayer(28552): signal application thread
12-15 17:36:54.565: V/MediaPlayer(28552): callback application
12-15 17:36:54.565: V/MediaPlayer(28552): back from callback
12-15 17:36:54.565: V/MediaPlayer(28552): prepare complete - status=0
12-15 17:36:54.565: V/MediaPlayer(28552): start
12-15 17:36:54.575: E/MediaPlayer(28552): mOnVideoSizeChangedListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_SET_VIDEO_SIZE message.
12-15 17:36:54.575: I/MediaPlayer(28552): Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
12-15 17:36:54.575: E/MediaPlayer(28552): mOnPreparedListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_PREPARED message.
12-15 17:36:54.605: D/memalloc(28552): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d609000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:51
12-15 17:36:55.826: D/memalloc(28552): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5dba1000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:58
12-15 17:36:55.866: D/memalloc(28552): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5df39000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:64
12-15 17:36:55.916: D/memalloc(28552): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5e2d1000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:70
12-15 17:36:56.167: V/MediaPlayer(28552): stop
12-15 17:36:56.357: W/MediaPlayer-JNI(28552): MediaPlayer finalized without being released
12-15 17:36:56.357: V/MediaPlayer(28552): setListener
12-15 17:36:56.357: V/MediaPlayer(28552): disconnect
12-15 17:36:56.367: V/MediaPlayer(28552): destructor
12-15 17:36:56.367: V/MediaPlayer(28552): disconnect
12-15 17:36:56.367: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1018K, 6% free 50943K/53987K, paused 18ms
12-15 17:36:56.417: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 25044K, 47% free 30901K/58083K, paused 15ms
12-15 17:36:56.457: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1001K, 40% free 34902K/58083K, paused 16ms
12-15 17:36:56.537: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1001K, 30% free 40904K/58083K, paused 1ms+6ms
12-15 17:36:56.597: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1501K, 23% free 44905K/58083K, paused 15ms
12-15 17:36:56.617: V/MediaPlayer(28552): constructor
12-15 17:36:56.617: V/MediaPlayer(28552): setListener
12-15 17:36:56.617: V/MediaPlayer(28552): setDataSource(49, 17037044, 211255)
12-15 17:36:56.627: V/MediaPlayer(28552): setVideoSurfaceTexture
12-15 17:36:56.627: V/MediaPlayer(28552): prepare
12-15 17:36:56.627: V/MediaPlayer(28552): message received msg=5, ext1=0, ext2=0
12-15 17:36:56.627: V/MediaPlayer(28552): New video size 0 x 0
12-15 17:36:56.627: V/MediaPlayer(28552): callback application
12-15 17:36:56.627: V/MediaPlayer(28552): back from callback
12-15 17:36:56.627: V/MediaPlayer(28552): message received msg=1, ext1=0, ext2=0
12-15 17:36:56.627: V/MediaPlayer(28552): prepared
12-15 17:36:56.627: V/MediaPlayer(28552): signal application thread
12-15 17:36:56.627: V/MediaPlayer(28552): callback application
12-15 17:36:56.627: V/MediaPlayer(28552): back from callback
12-15 17:36:56.627: V/MediaPlayer(28552): prepare complete - status=0
12-15 17:36:56.627: V/MediaPlayer(28552): start
12-15 17:36:56.637: E/MediaPlayer(28552): mOnVideoSizeChangedListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_SET_VIDEO_SIZE message.
12-15 17:36:56.637: I/MediaPlayer(28552): Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
12-15 17:36:56.637: E/MediaPlayer(28552): mOnPreparedListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_PREPARED message.
12-15 17:36:56.657: D/memalloc(28552): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5d609000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:51
12-15 17:36:57.478: D/memalloc(28552): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x5dba1000 size:3768320 offset:0 fd:58
12-15 17:36:57.738: V/MediaPlayer(28552): stop
12-15 17:36:57.878: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1515K, 14% free 50456K/58083K, paused 16ms
12-15 17:36:57.908: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 506K, 9% free 52951K/58083K, paused 17ms
12-15 17:36:57.948: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 500K, 9% free 54951K/60131K, paused 16ms
12-15 17:36:57.979: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 500K, 9% free 56952K/62179K, paused 16ms
12-15 17:36:58.019: I/dalvikvm-heap(28552): Clamp target GC heap from 65.421MB to 64.000MB
12-15 17:36:58.019: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 500K, 9% free 58952K/64227K, paused 16ms
12-15 17:36:58.019: I/dalvikvm-heap(28552): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 2048016-byte allocation
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm-heap(28552): Clamp target GC heap from 65.414MB to 64.000MB
12-15 17:36:58.049: D/dalvikvm(28552): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 9% free 58942K/64227K, paused 27ms
12-15 17:36:58.049: E/dalvikvm-heap(28552): Out of memory on a 2048016-byte allocation.
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40c5ccd0 self=0x15d0f60
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   | sysTid=28552 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1075107208
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=99 stm=31 core=0
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:618)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:593)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:445)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:775)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1968)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:677)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.graphics.drawable.LevelListDrawable.inflate(LevelListDrawable.java:127)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:869)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:806)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1953)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:109)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:278)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at com.fun2draw.Collection1Char1.onCreate(Collection1Char1.java:39)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
12-15 17:36:58.049: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-15 17:36:58.059: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-15 17:36:58.059: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
12-15 17:36:58.059: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-15 17:36:58.059: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-15 17:36:58.059: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
12-15 17:36:58.059: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
12-15 17:36:58.059: I/dalvikvm(28552):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-15 17:36:58.059: D/AndroidRuntime(28552): Shutting down VM
12-15 17:36:58.059: W/dalvikvm(28552): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c5ba68)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fun2draw/com.fun2draw.Collection1Char1}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #133: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #133: Error inflating class <unknown>
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:278)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at com.fun2draw.Collection1Char1.onCreate(Collection1Char1.java:39)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    ... 11 more
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    ... 24 more
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:618)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:593)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:445)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:775)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1968)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:677)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.graphics.drawable.LevelListDrawable.inflate(LevelListDrawable.java:127)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:869)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:806)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1953)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:109)
12-15 17:36:58.069: E/AndroidRuntime(28552):    ... 27 more
12-15 17:37:09.571: I/Process(28552): Sending signal. PID: 28552 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Looks like you're doing some AV as part of this and running low on memory based on the last error. Are you finishing the launched activity? If not you should consider doing this, additionally you could try finishing the launching activity (this activity).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()

Comment: Could you include the code for your collection1Char1 class? It looks like you got a memory leak going, and the error points to the onCreate method in the activities you are calling. When they are finished, are all their resources recycled properly?

Comment: For the collection1Char1 class, I override the onStop() method. Then I call the super.onStop() method, stop and then set the media player in that class to null, and call the finish() method. But I think I've found a solution that works in most cases (see my reply to SylvainL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that you have some sort of memory pressure in your collection1Char1 activity.  You should wait a few seconds before launching the next activity to leave the system some time to recover the resources.

Comment: Thanks, SylvainL. This seems to have been the cause behind my problems. I added a time delay to the CharPicker class for about 500ms. Now when I leave the first activity and try to launch the second activity quickly, it won't launch the activity just yet. The user won't be able to launch the second activity until after the 500ms have passed.